# How to design reverse geocode thousands of lat,lng fed into IOT platform from GPS Trackers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, geocoding, aws-iot, reverse-geocoding

We have a system where there is a number of asset trackers which are sending location data every 15 mins. with LAT, LNG values from GPS device. These are sent to MQTT broker AWS IOT and using AWS IOT rule engine it is forwarded to AWS Lambda where it processes this data. While processing we are invoking reverse geocoding API to fill in the location info and store it in the database. And on the client-side, it is displayed to the user.
Now the issue is:
Since our asset trackers are growing the cost of reverse geocoding is way too much. We tried cost-effective solutions (like other reverse geocoding providers) but still, the cost keeps getting higher.

Another solution was to reverse geocode when a client requests the page but that is causing performance issues and sometimes failure in decoding due to reverse geocoding API errors.

We also thought about reducing asset tracker duration from 15 mins to 30 mins but customer or user is not happy as they want to see frequent updates.

Can anyone help with a better design approach? Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Are you prepared to write your own API and maintain your own database of geo-tagged locations?

Comment: I went that path too but did not find anything promising. One of them was PostGIS Tiger DB but the documentation is sparse for setting it up on AWS EC2. Please let me know if you have any ideas here. thank you  for going through it.

Comment: @KunalD. Have you made progress with this? I'm interested to learn if you've found a good solution?

Comment: Hi @Elliveny, No luck as of now. I have subscribed to a third-party service named bigdatacloud, which offers competitive pricing for reverse geocoding.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked if the reverse geocoding api can take multiple entries?
So that you might be able to make requests in batch rather than 1 API call per geolocation point.

Comment: This answer could be posted as a comment instead.

Comment: if StackOverFlow allows it when you are a new joiner, then I'd have done it!